Find $x^\circ$ in triangle below if if $AM = MC = BC$
Calculate $x^\circ$ if $AM = MC = BC$.
(Answer:$90^\circ$)


I try:
$ \angle CMB \cong \angle MBC = \frac{180^\circ-x}{2}$
$ \therefore \angle CMB \cong \angle MBC = 90^\circ -\frac{x}{2}$
$ \angle A = 180^\circ - (90^\circ -\frac{x}{2} + \frac{37^\circ}{2}+x)$
$ \therefore \angle A=\frac{143^\circ}{2}+\frac{x}{2}$
$ \angle BMA = 90^\circ - \frac{x}{2}$
How do I finish?



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Let $\,AM=MC=BC=a>0$.
By applying the law of cosines to the triangle $ABC$,
we get that $\;AB=a\sqrt{5-4\cos x^\circ}\,.$
On the other hand, it results that
$M\hat BC=\dfrac{180^\circ-x^\circ}2=90^\circ-\dfrac{x^\circ}2\quad$ and $A\hat MB=M\hat BC+x^\circ=90^\circ+\dfrac{x^\circ}2\;.$
By applying the law of sines to the triangle $ABM$,
it follows that
$\dfrac{AB}{\sin\left(90^\circ+\frac{x^\circ}2\right)}=\dfrac{AM}{\sin\left(\frac{37^\circ}2\right)}\;\;,$
$\dfrac{a\sqrt{5-4\cos x^\circ}}{\cos\left(\frac{x^\circ}2\right)}=\dfrac a {\sin\left(\frac{37^\circ}2\right)}\;\;,$
$\sin\left(\frac{37^\circ}2\right)\sqrt{5-4\cos x^\circ}=\cos\left(\frac{x^\circ}2\right)\;\;,$
$\sin^2\!\left(\frac{37^\circ}2\right)(5-4\cos x^\circ)=\dfrac{1+\cos x^\circ}2\;\;,$
$\sin^2\!\left(\frac{37^\circ}2\right)(10-8\cos x^\circ)=1+\cos x^\circ\;\;,$
$\cos x^\circ=\dfrac{10\sin^2\!\left(\frac{37^\circ}2\right)-1}{1+8\sin^2\!\left(\frac{37^\circ}2\right)}\approx0.003778792\;,\quad$ hence ,
$x^\circ\approx89.78349066^\circ$.
Actually $\,x^\circ$ is not exactly $\,90^\circ\,.$

Addendum:

We can also solve this exercise by associating the $\frac{37^\circ}2$ angle with a $1:3:\sqrt{10}$ right-angled triangle.
By drawing two perpendicular lines to the ray $BM$ from the points $A$ and $C$, we get three congruent right-angled triangles which are $ADM$, $MEC$ and $BEC$.
Since the right-angled triangle $ABD$ has a $\frac{37^\circ}2$ angle, it follows that $\,BD=3k\,$ and $\,AD=k\,.$
But $\,DM=\dfrac{BD}3=k\,,\,$ hence $\,AD=DM\,,\,$ consequently $ADM$ is an isosceles right triangle and $\,A\hat MD=45^\circ\,.$
On the other hand,
$A\hat MD=B\hat MC=\dfrac{180^\circ-x^\circ}2=90^\circ-\dfrac{x^\circ}2\,.$
Therefore ,
$90^\circ-\dfrac{x^\circ}2=45^\circ\;\;,\;\;$ from which we get that
$x^\circ=90^\circ\,.$
This solution is not exact because actually $1:3:\sqrt{10}$ right-angled triangles do not have exactly a $\frac{37^\circ}2$ angle.

Very good...that's the idea  thank you

Let $\alpha$ denote $\angle ABM$. As correctly pointed out in the comments, I'm assuming $\alpha=\arctan\frac13$.
Since $CM=CB$, we know $\angle CMB=\angle CBM=\frac\pi2-\frac x2^\circ$. Let this angle be $\beta$. Then $\angle CBA=\beta+\alpha, \angle CAB=\beta-\alpha$.
Since $\frac{CA}{CB}=2$, by Law of Sines, we know that $$\sin(\beta+\alpha)=2\sin(\beta-\alpha).$$
$$\iff\sin\beta\cos\alpha+\cos\beta\sin\alpha=2(\sin\beta\cos\alpha-\cos\beta\sin\alpha)$$
$$\iff\sin\beta\cos\alpha=3\cos\beta\sin\alpha$$
$$\iff\tan\beta=3\tan\alpha=1$$
So $\beta=\frac\pi4$, giving $x^\circ=90^\circ$.

Tesla, you wrote that $\angle CMB=\angle CBM=\frac\pi2-x^\circ$, but actually $\angle CMB=\angle CBM=\frac\pi2-\mathbf{\color{red}{\frac{x^\circ}2}}$.

Consider the general case where $\angle ABM=\alpha$ and $\angle MBC=\angle BMC=\theta$. Then$\angle MAB=\theta-\alpha$. The sine rule applied to triangles $AMB$ and $BMC$ gives
$$\frac{|AM|}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{|BM|}{\sin(\theta-\alpha)}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{|MC|}{\sin\theta}=\frac{|BM|}{\sin2\theta}.$$
Since $|AM|=|MC|$, division yields
$$\sin\theta\sin(\theta-\alpha)=\sin2\theta\sin\alpha.$$
By expanding $\sin(\theta-\alpha)$ as $\sin\theta\cos\alpha-\cos\theta\sin\alpha$ and $\sin2\theta$ as $2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, gathering terms, and then dividing through by $\sin\theta\cos\theta\cos\alpha$, we get
$$\tan\theta=3\tan\alpha.$$
In order to get $2\theta=90^\circ$, we need $\alpha=\arctan\frac13\approx18.4349488^\circ$. If $\alpha=18.5^\circ$, then $2\theta\approx90.2165093^\circ$.
